# Sources for Monarch

Tags: monaco-editor

Are the sources available for the [Monarch](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/monarch.html) parser/lexer?

I have looked into the `monaco-editor` repository, but the only [relevant file](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor/blob/master/website/monarch/monarch.js) seems to be a wrapper. There are also [a few classes](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor/blob/d7ef525b1d2ab817b9542644bf53af7ce2bd4042/website/playground/monaco.d.ts.txt#L5137) defined in the source of the Monaco editor, but it looks very lightweight given the capabilities offered by the language, so I am guessing there is more "meat" under the hood somewhere.

It would be helpful either to point to the implementation of Monarch within Monaco, or ideally to a standalone implementation if it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want.

[`master` branch](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/tree/master/src/vs/editor/standalone/common/monarch)

[current `HEAD` at the time of this writing](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/tree/c406cb40cf96f3edc222c223bdd93e59207a4da1/src/vs/editor/standalone/common/monarch) (in case the path to `master` changes later when someone clicks on this answer two years later :))